# how to move canvas more smoother

Tags: android, canvas

I am moving Drawn Circle Shape by onDraw() with Timer. But it is not smooth moving just like moving setMargin of relative layout. How can I fix it ?
Here is my code for Circle Shape !

```
public class Circle extends View{
int y =0 ;


public Circle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
protected void  onDraw(Canvas c){
    super.onDraw(c);
    Paint p=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    c.drawCircle(100,y,10,p);

}


}
```

Here is my code for MainActivity!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    LinearLayout rl=new LinearLayout(this);
    setContentView(rl);
    rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    final Circle c = new Circle(this);
    rl.addView(c);
    Timer t=new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            c.y+=4;
            c.postInvalidate();
        }
    };
    t.schedule(task,0,20);
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

It is just like draft moving. I've no idea how to fix it. Is there any other way for smooth moving. Somebody please help me !!

Comment: You may try to lower the value of timer or remove it completely and try it.

Comment: yes.. smooth in lower value but I need such high value .. thank you

Comment: Then you can reduce this value c.y+=4; to lower increments

Comment: sorry ... I understand what you mean .. How to lower timer value .. please help me !!

Comment: What I meant is either you can lower the timer values or you can lower the increment of y. In case you lower the timer values, you will have more draw calls thereby making your draw look smooth. Else if you lower the "y" increment, then in each draw, the circles would look closer thereby giving smooth effect.

Comment: Your idea is good  .. but it can't be smoother! sorry bro i'm dull .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving 4 pixels every 20 milliseconds is equivalent to moving it 4 pixels 50 times per second, which translates to 200 pixels every second.

There are several things you should consider here:

- Updating at 50 updates per second (ie. every 20 ms) is generally pretty high for a mobile device. I would honestly cut that a lot, to let's say, 30 ms (or 33.3 updates per second), or even a bit lower. I recall reading somewhere that the lowest FPS a person can see before appearing choppy is between 24 and 26 FPS (please someone correct me if that number is off).

Lowering the number of updates you do per second will lower the distance at which your image travels over time, thereby smoothing it out. Be warned, too low (ie. the threshold I mentioned) and your game will also appear choppy.

- I wouldn't recommend using just pixels. If you're working with Android, you're going to be working with tons of different screen sizes, which means that 4-pixel-movement will NOT look the same on all devices. If you're developing a game, this is going to create serious discrepancies among devices and variations in gameplay. The solution? Everyone has their opinion, but mine is generally to do everything in percentage variations of the screen.

That being said, you could do something like:

```
float speed = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.002f; 
// you're obviously going to have to adjust the '0.002f' to what works 
// with you and your thread's update rate per second. May also want to use
// widthPixels depending on your orientation
```

In summation:

Reduce the number of updates you're doing per second, possibly reduce the distance you're traversing with each update call, and try to do everything in a way that relates to the dynamic screen size.